# Unpacking function return values to single value and tuple, in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I often use library functions which return many values in a tuple:

```
def f():
    return "a", "b", "c", "d"
```

Is it possible to (in a single step) unpack the first value while keeping the rest in a tuple? I.e. do this:

```
ret = f()
a, b_to_d = ret[0], ret[1:]
```

but in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the `*` syntax below:

```
>>> def f():
...  return 1,2,3,4
...
>>> a,*b = f()
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4]
>>> a,*b,c = f()  # * can be used in other positions, too
>>> a,b,c
(1, [2, 3], 4)
```